# QGIS python error for XY tools plug in, even after installing xlrd and xlw modules!

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, excel, tools, indexerror

As I am a complete beginner, I had troubles getting the XY tools plug in running. Now that the xlrd and xlw module error has disappeared after installment of said modules, I can finally choose the X and Y axis. But after doing so I get the following error message after confirmation:

`File "/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins/xytools/xytools.py", line 162, in excelOpen self.loadSheetAsLayer(provider)
File "/Users/metzi/.qgis2/python/plugins/xytools/xytools.py", line 211, in loadSheetAsLayer x=row[self.layerInfo[self.layer].xIdx] IndexError: list index out of range`

The .xls file in use should be fine, since it's from a Prof in a geomatics class and already in use for 4 years. Can anybody help a total beginner?

Answer (score 1):

This post provides this troubleshoot option [[Qgis-user] XY Tools error](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2014-September/029138.html)

> After trying around, it works if there is now other layer loaded (an empty qgis project)  and the CRS of the qgis-project is set to the CRS of the x/y-data of the table.
>   (The CRS of the loaded data will be set to the CRS of the project.)